# Wordpress theme using Isotope and post views

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope filtering on my wordpress theme.
The posts are displayed as boxes and filtered by category.

I would like to change the size of the boxes (add an aditional css class) based on the number of post views, so that the most visited posts would be the largest and so on ...

Any suggestions on how to get the number of post views and set this additional class based on number of views ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to track the number of views.
take a look at this: [Track post views without using a plugin](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/super-useful-wordpress-hacks-and-snippets)(need to scroll)
Get this running first.

Comment: this seems to take care of the view count. +1

Comment: If you can get this running, I'll get back at the other part of the question

Comment: this should work, however I will be using a lightbox dialog to display the post content so the setPostViews(get_the_ID()); function will have another caller not single.php

Comment: If you only want to trigger it when the lightbox pops up you will need an ajax call

Comment: I understand. Any suggestion on the second part of the problem /

Comment: I would suggest you make a function which echo's a class based on the nr of views. And call it at the place you need it. might want to build in checks like `is_single`